# How to make an API call in solidity using chainlink?

Tags: oracle, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I need to replace "uint256 player" with the response from the server in my smart contract using chainlink.
Actually, I found similar questions here, but their answers are either outdated or unsuitable in my case.

```
//Contract based on https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc721
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MyT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

contract MyNFT is Ownable {

    function payToStartGame(uint256 player) external payable {

        payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);

        if (player > 10) {
          revert("Game started, try again later");
        }
    }

}
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: You need to make an external contract call to the Chainlink contract. I don't know the interface you're trying to use so I can' help further.

Comment: You need to add more information and context to get help here.